# How to set up Sublime Text 2 for Ruby Tests (Windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, sublimetext2, ruby-test

I'm following the Rails Tutorial (Hartl), and having some trouble in section 3.6.4 "Tests Inside Sublime Text".

Running Windows 7 (I know, not optimal, but what I have for now).
I followed the steps at https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests#settings and successfully cloned the repository to the %APPDATA/Sublime Text 2/Packages/ directory on my machine.

My problem is with the "Settings" section - I'm instructed to:

> "Make a copy of RubyTest.sublime-settings file to ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/ and make your changes."

No problem finding the file.  But the directory appears to be specific to OS-X.  It's not at all clear to me where the equivalent location would be in Windows.  I assume that I need to drop a copy of the file in a suitable location where Sublime Text 2 can read it, but I'm not any wiser about that location after several hours of searching.

Where does the "RubyTest.sublime-settings" file go in Windows??

Appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you cloned the repo to :

```
%APPDATA/Sublime Text 2/Packages/
```

So the "RubyTest.sublime-settings" would go into:

```
%APPDATA/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User
```

Comment: thanks for the answer!  I threw in the towel on Windows, bought a Macbook Pro, learning Ruby and Rails in that environment.  Can't tell you if that solves it without going back to the Windows machine, but hopefully it's helpful to someone else...